# How to make a temporary email service

Tags: email-server

How to make a temporary email service like tempomail, mailinator, mailexpire or similar ?

How does it work ?

How can I setup such service on a Debian box ?

Comment: That's kind of an odd question.  Why would you make something like this so temporary?  It's really easy to install such an application but it'll take time and eduction to set it up right.  Seems sad that it's the subject of such temporary effort.

Comment: And for the record, Postfix is pretty solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into any specifics you will need a domain name and a place you can solidly host a mail server on port 25.  That's it.  Just configure your mail server to accept any messages for your domain and forward them to you.

Answer (score 1):

Once this has been done you'll need to setup a web base GUI interface that will in fact do a simple GREP for the given "TO" email address on the mailbox used to "Foward All" emails and display them.

I know that the theory is simpler than the practice :)